# Build from a Solution folder into a specific subfolder of the output folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build

I know how to move built .dlls to a folder using post-build events to copy the files, or using the output path setting.

Can I do something like that for all projects in a solution folder, where I wouldn't need to set up build events. I want all projects in a solution folder "SomeDir" to be moved to a "SomeDir" folder when built. 
"SomeDir" would be the subfolder of the main output folder

Thanks

Comment: I don't think, there's other option in Visual studio for post build events, but you could create an exe or .bat to copy all the build dlls to your destination directory, and execute that exe at the last building project- post build event.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up refactoring the solution which eliminated the need to do this altogether.